# How can I implement downward arrow on a div?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a price marker like this: [image] .  Sometimes, it will have `Open` and the Favorite (heart) attached to the price and sometimes it won't.

I've managed to create most of it (see snippet).  I used the `::before` pseudo class to render the Favorite part. And I've used `::after` to deal with the Open part.

The last piece of the puzzle is the downward arrow. Since both `::before` and `::after` can only be used once, I am out of those types of tricks.

So how do I implement the downward arrow?  P.S. Note that there is a border around the price and it should envelope the arrow as well.

```css
    body {
      background-color: lightsalmon;
      transform: scale(4.0);
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }

    .home-price {
      color: white;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      width: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 2px;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 300;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }

    .home-sale {
      background-color: #009934;
      border-color: #F2F5F3;
    }

    .home-hot {
      background-color: #C81845;
      border-color: #F5F2F3;
    }

    .home-foreclosed {
      background-color: #FBA902;
      border-color: #F6F5F2;
    }

    /* Open House Marker */
    .home-price::after {
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: white;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border-spacing: 1px;
      content: "OPEN";
      color: white;
      background-color: #586371;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
      font-size: 8px;
      font-weight: 300;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      left: -1px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 25px;
    }

    /* Favorite Marker */
    .home-price::before {
      content: "♥";
      color: red;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 46px;     
      top: -8px;
      text-shadow:  white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px,
                    white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px;

    }
```

```html
  <div style="height: 200px;margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="home-price home-hot">$899K</div>
    <div class="home-price home-sale">$1.29M</div>
    <div class="home-price home-foreclosed">$11.8M</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You don't need to use pseudo classes, just add an <i> element with a class inside your home-price div work over that

Comment: @Juanín the `<i>` for what?  For the Open part or Favorite or the downward arrow.  I don't really follow how that would work.  Can you proivde an example?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what I meant was exactly what Ian Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Juanin means to move the "Open" & "Heart" contents to  elements.
Which in turn will free up the pseudo before & after for the downarrows.

Here is a rough fiddle to show what he means.

https://jsfiddle.net/wd0um6q9/2/

and the HTML Markup:

```
  <div style="height: 200px;margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="home-price home-hot"><i class="open">Open</i><i class="heart"></i>$899K</div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Open House Marker */
    .open {
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: white;
      border-radius: 2px;
      border-spacing: 1px;
      color: white;
      background-color: #586371;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
      font-size: 8px;
      font-weight: 300;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
      left: -1px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 25px;
    }

    /* Favorite Marker */
    .heart:before {
      content: "♥";
      color: red;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 46px;     
      top: -8px;
      text-shadow:  white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px,
                    white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px,   
                    white 0px 0px 1px;

    }
```